# Errors when many clients connect to Go server

Tags: sockets, go, goroutine

full code could download at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/e1Ir__Dq_gE

Could anyone help me to improve this sample code to zero bug?
I think it will help us to develop a bug free client / server code.

my develop steps:

1. Create a server which could handle multiple connections by goroutine.
2. Build a client which works fine with simple protocol.
3. Expand the client to simulate multiple clients (with option -n=1000 clients as default)
4. TODO: try to reduce lock of server
5. TODO: try to use bufio to enhance throughput

I found this code is very unstable contains with three problems:

1. launch 1000 clients, one of them occurs a  EOF when reading from server.
2. launch 1050 clients, got too many open files soon (No any clients opened).
3. launch 1020 clients, got runtime error with long trace stacks.

   ```
   Start pollServer: pipe: too many open files
   panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

   [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x4650d0]
   ```

Here I paste my more simplified code.

```
const ClientCount = 1000
func main() {
    srvAddr := "127.0.0.1:10000"
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(ClientCount)
    for i := 0; i < ClientCount; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            client(i, srvAddr)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
func client(i int, srvAddr string) {
    conn, e := net.Dial("tcp", srvAddr)
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Err:Dial():", e)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    conn.SetTimeout(proto.LINK_TIMEOUT_NS)
    defer func() {
        conn.Close()
    }()

    l1 := proto.L1{uint32(i), uint16(rand.Uint32() % 10000)}
    log.Println(conn.LocalAddr(), "WL1", l1)
    e = binary.Write(conn, binary.BigEndian, &l1)
    if e == os.EOF {
        return
    }
    if e != nil {
        return
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This site may be of help. It gives a thorough overview with examples on networking code in Go: http://jan.newmarch.name/go/

Comment: What operating system are you running the client/server on?

Comment: Problem #2 is probably casued by the 1024 file descriptor limit on your OS. Also you defer conn.Close() twice which might be a problem.

Comment: @RCE, thanks, I'm sure problem #2 is caused by ulimit -n 1024. I've removed the defer conn.Close() twice bug, but it can not get any help in this problem.

Comment: What will be the protocol ? Is it really needed to have so many sockets open at the same time ? You'll have system resources used for each one of these open sockets.

Answer (score 1):

This answer on serverfault [1] suggests that for servers that can handle a lot of connections, setting a higher ulimit is the thing to do.  Also check for application leaks of memory or file descriptor leaks using lsof.

```
ulimit -n 99999
```

[1] https://serverfault.com/a/48820/110909